# Does there exist a rational number, satisfying specific condition?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, number-theory, limits, algebraic-number-theory

Does there exist such rational number $q>1$, that
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 1}
  \int_0^\varepsilon \left(1+\left(\frac{t^q}{1-t^q}\right)^{q-1}\right)^{1/q}dt
$$ is algebraic?

I do not know any such number, but I can not explain why there should not be one either.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how did you come upon this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $q=1$ the expression collapses into $$ \lim_{\varepsilon\to 1} \int_0^\varepsilon 2\,dt $$ so the limit is $2$, which is algebraic.

Comment: Thank you! I did not notice at first that trivial solution to my question. Still, I wonder, if there are some other...